# Subtracting 2 decimal numbers from each other

Tags: javascript

In javascript, I'm doing this subtraction:
`1.0589 - 1.0584`

To my best math knowledge, the result should be:
 `0.0005`

But it's not in javascript. The result I get is:
`0.0004999999999999449`

Am I missing something?

Comment: You might be interested to read this article:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: roundNumber(0.0004999999999999449,4) //returns 0.0005

you just missing a function to round the decimal places.
Try above function.